Идентификатор подсети в адресе ipv6?
Какой идентификатор подсети в индивидуальном IPv6-адресе 2001:db8:acad::aaaa:1234/64?

длина ipv6-адреса - 128 бит. 64 (указанная вами длина маски) - это, очевидно, будет половина. сможете первую половину битов в вашем адресе выделить? p.s. полная запись вашего адреса: 2001:0db8:acad:0000:0000:0000:aaaa:1234

Этот вопрос, заданный именно в таком виде:

Какой идентификатор подсети в индивидуальном IPv6-адресе
2001:db8:acad::aaaa:1234/64?

был из домашнего задания и мой ответ изначально был с такой логикой:

Для адреса 2001:db8:acad::aaaa:1234/64:

префикс длиной в 64 бита означает, что первые 64 бита определяют сеть и подсеть - значение 2001:db8:acad:0000
это идентификатор подсети, так как все, что после первых 64 бит, не относится к подсети, а является идентификатором интерфейса
 >

Таким образом полный идентификатор подсети: 2001:db8:acad:0000 или
2001:db8:acad::/64

Но преподавателя этот ответ не устроил, он посчитал, что правильным ответ на этот вопрос должен быть - 0 (только четвертый хекстет), согласно вот этой картинки из презенташки урока:

В общем, оказался контекст и человеческий фактор)
